# How to extract the URL following an HTTPPost in Android

Tags: java, android, url, http-post

I'm scratching my head at this problem that I can't seem to figure out. What I'm trying to do is extract the URL following the HTTPpost. This will allow me to go through the Oauth process.

Currently I'm extracting the whole website into my entity.

For example: The data will be posted to https://mysite.com/login and will redirect after the post to https://mysite.com/dashboard?code=3593085390859082093720

How does one extract the url?

If you need any more information or can direct me in the right direction, all is appreciated! Thank you!

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button ok,back,exit;
TextView result;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Login button clicked
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);

    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

}

public void postLoginData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://mysite.com/login");

    try {
        // Add user name and password
     EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
     String username = uname.getText().toString();

     EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
     String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pseudonym_session[unique_id]", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pseudonym_session[password]", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("CANVAS", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("CANVAS", str);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
        String ResponseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
         Log.w("CANVAS", "TRUE");
         result.setText("Login successful");   
        }else
        {
         Log.w("CANVAS", "FALSE");
         result.setText(ResponseBody); 
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
 String line = "";
 StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
 // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
 // Read response until the end
 try {
  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    total.append(line); 
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 // Return full string
 return total;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if(view == ok){
    postLoginData();
  }
}

}
```

Comment: You would have to make your server send back the url in the post response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set a redirect handler, you can get back from the response the location the server's sending you to. here's a snippet of code I was just playing with... (and I should point out, if you DON'T set a redirect handler, you'll just get redirected to the final destination, which might be the login screen itself)

```
DefaultHttpClient htc = getHttpClient();
htc.setRedirectHandler(new RedirectHandler() {
  @Override
  public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "isRedirectRequested, response: " + response.toString());
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
      throws ProtocolException
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationURI, response: " + response.toString());
    return null;
  }
});
HttpResponse resp = null;
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
try
{
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(spec);
  resp = htc.execute(get);
  for (Header hdr : resp.getAllHeaders())
    Log.d(TAG, "header " + hdr.getName() + " -> " + hdr.getValue());
  ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to " + spec, e);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm going to investigate and create something similar.

Comment: that's if i want to get the parameters from redirect url , must use HTTP GET MEthod ?

Answer (score 0):

Search for a substring in the HttpPost url